# Database connectivity

Tags: asp.net, oracle

How can I establish the database connection with the back end of oracle10g express edition with the front end of asp.net?. Please send the source code.

Comment: This might give you some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782181/connect-to-an-oracle-10g-database-with-microsoft-odbc-for-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Once you've [downloaded the appropriate driver](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) you reference the assembly in your project you could perform SQL queries against the database:

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo;";
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // TODO: exploit the results
        }
    }
}
```

Reading the [technical articles](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) accompanying the driver might also be useful.