# Accessing Oracle SQL Developer database from VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle

New to VBA and returning to SQL after 15 years. I'm am trying to use VBA to run SQL commands to download data into excel for further manipulation.

I have SQL Developer installed on my machine and I am able to access the database using the UI. I have figured out how to connect to the database and run a query within the SQL Developer interface, but honestly, I'm not an IT guy.

Any ideas how to do this? Even basic command line commands to connect to the database and run the query would be helpful.

I found this code on another site, but I'm having trouble getting my connection string to work. My macro errors out on the cnn.Open statement and says the Provider is not installed. I think it's because PROVIDER is set up for a different SQL Database type, but I can't seem to get the connection string to work.

I know my username and password, which I have successfully used to connect in the SQL Developer UI. I'm not sure what to put for remote IP address or database. Would that be the hostname and the SID in the connection properties dialog in SQL Developer? (The hostname looks more like a url without the http than an ip address. Not sure if hostname and ip address is an interchangeable term).

```
Sub Download_Reports()
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String


'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
   'Make sure to change:
       '1: PASSWORD
       '2: USERNAME
       '3: REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS
       '4: DATABASE
    ConnectionString = "Provider=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE;Password=PASSWORD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=USERNAME;Data Source=REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=DATABASE"

    'Opens connection to the database
    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900


    'This is your actual MS SQL query that you need to run; you should check this query first using a more robust SQL editor (such as HeidiSQL) to ensure your query is valid
    StrQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM tbl_table"


    'Performs the actual query
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub
```

I'm needing help with my connection string. Can anyone help me with this?
I'm connecting to a database via Oracle SQL Developer. I am able to connect within the UI by providing the following items:

1. Connection Name - got it.
2. myUsername - got it.
3. myPassword - got it.
4. Connection Type = Basic, Role = default
5. myHostname - got it.
6. myPort - got it.
7. mySID - got it.

However, I am unable to get my connection string to work in VBA. When I run the script I get

> "Run-time Error '3076'. Provider cannot be found.

It may not be properly installed" on the line beginning with cnn.open.

Comment: Is the Oracle driver installed? Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10917600/7948962

Comment: You have to download and install **Oracle Provider for OLE DB**, you can download it from [ODAC Runtime Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdeploy-4242173.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL Developer.