# Connect to Oracle database without using TNS Listener

Tags: oracle, listener, tns

Just out of curiosity, a few days ago we had a discussion about whether there is a way to connect to the DB without using TNS Listener, the connection must be made by any program SQLPlus. Net, ODBC, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically only [local connections can avoid the listener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/network.htm#BHCDIGGC) (ie you have to be already logged on to the machine that the database instance is running on).

Rather than relying on a listener to fork out a process to act on behalf of the connection, this is done by the local process. Generally it means that the local user needs to be run as 'oracle' as well. Sort of equivalent to a console logic.

Comment: so, can i do LSNRCTL STOP and connect using SQLPlus? TIA

Comment: Yes, but you omit the @db component and so will need ORACLE_SID defined so that it knows which instance to try to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there isn't one magic bullet, but there are several ways.

For ODBC, have a look at [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782181/connect-to-an-oracle-10g-database-with-microsoft-odbc-for-oracle)

There's a lot of good info at [Connectionstrings.com/oracle](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle) as well.

Answer (score -1):

You connect to Oracle via a client, such as sqplplus, or a java program (or tool) utilizing a protocol such as SQL*NET or JDBC (as examples) through the listener. The listener in turn forks a process on the target database (or assigns the connection to an existing process if you use shared servers).